# SVG waiting for document to be ready in javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I have an svg that I need to work on client. Everything is fine, but sometimes the document of the svgDoc-variable is not ready.

The file is 3MB - we need to work on that, but it is delivered from a subsupplier (export form a CAD system) so I cant rely on it to get much more handy.

And I know how to wait for the loading of the svg itself.

I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null

I have this code:

Html:

```
<object id="svg2" width="2000" type="image/svg+xml" data="test.svg" onload="afterSvgLoaded()"></object>
```

javascript:

```
    var svgDoc;

function afterSvgLoaded(){

var svg = document.getElementById("svg2"); 
svgDoc = svg.contentDocument;

//Does not work
console.log(svgDoc.getElementById('Lejemaalsnummer').getElementsByTagName('circle'));

//Does work - but I do not want to depend on timeouts
setTimeout("console.log(svgDoc.getElementById('Lejemaalsnummer').getElementsByTagName('circle'))",1000);

}
```

How can I test the readyness of the svgDoc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an onload event you can hook into that fires when the SVG has been loaded

```
<object id="svg2" onload="afterSvgLoaded()" width="2000" type="image/svg+xml" data="localFile.svg"></object>
```

Comment: Thanks, but wrong issue.... the waiting for the actual svg to load works. Its after that, when I want to "query" the document... but yes, I should just use the onload..there, done, revised the question

Comment: If that's the case, it's a UA bug, report it to the UAs bug tracker.

Comment: Well.... seems that the method I used for checking only APPARENTLY worked like the onload. For small documents it did work as such, but for larger it triggered my code, after the svg had been transfered to client, but before it was available in full for manipulation. I did not see this at first when I implemented the onload, but guess somethings were cached... it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a `<div>` instead of an `<object>`, load the SVG with `xmlHttpRequest()` and do the stuff you need to do when the `onload` callback is called.  Maybe something like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "test.svg", true);
// Just for safety; not needed if the SVG is served with the correct MIME type:
xmlHttpRequest.overrideMimeType("image/svg+ xml");
xhr.onload = function (e) {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      var svgDoc = xhr.responseXML;
      console.log(svgDoc.getElementById('Lejemaalsnummer').getElementsByTagName('circle'));
    } else {
      console.error(xhr.statusText);
    }
  }
};
xhr.onerror = function (e) {
  console.error(xhr.statusText);
};
xhr.send(null);
```

(This is basically a modifed [MDN sample](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Example.3A_send_a_file_to_the_console_log).)